# I am not getting data in crystal reports which is made using visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

Creating crystal Reports.

Using Visual Studio 2019 , database is connected with postgres.

**Problem** -I am working on a crystal reports , need to create crystal reports in visual studio from postgres.
I have already created the crystal report but the problem is ,I only get first letter of the string and rest of the string is missing .
I am not able to get my full string [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoEmm.png)

This is the report which I have already made. How can I get my data ??

Comment: Have you checked width of field `Name` on crystal report designer? it might be too less/narrow that's why showing only one character. or maybe some formula is applied? or maybe from backend data coming have only one character in `Name` field. also, check type of `Name` and `Description` fields also it is showing demo (generated) data not real data i think ..?!!

Comment: I have already checked the width of the field .Actually I have created a crystal report with this steps mentioned in this link [link] (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/learn/crystal-reports-tutorials/crystal-report-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Steps are right. you need to verify what data is coming in this field.

Comment: Data which is coming in this field is live data which is fetched from postgres

Comment: Click on "Database" > "Show SQL Query...".  Then copy and paste the query your report is using into your preferred Query Analyzer tool and execute the query.  Does the Name column contain the full text or only the first character?  If the name column contains the full text for each name, then you may have some kind of formula field or field property that is causing the truncation.

Comment: I have solved my problem , there was a problem in postgres database of datatype ,so after change my data type from  'text' to 'character' .I have received my data properly.